# is there way to put text "cancel" and "ok" below the avatar buttons ? i mean that the avatar and the text need to be pressable when click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

is there a way to put the text "cancel" and "ok" below the avatar button? I mean that the avatar and the text need to be pressable when click.
I can't put the text below to every button and I don't understand what is my mistake.

[this is what I get now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDhut.jpg)

but I need the text below to every button and also must be also pressable same the image (it should be part of the button)

this is my example of code :

```
const OrderInformationScreen = props => {
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                backgroundColor: '#00BFFF',
                alignItems: 'flex-start',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                marginTop: 30,
                borderBottomWidth: 2,
                borderColor: 'blue',
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: 'space-evenly'

            }}
        >
            <Avatar
                size='large'
                containerStyle={{ marginTop: 30 }}
                activeOpacity={0.2}
                rounded
                source={require('../assets/down.png')} style={{ height: 80, width: 80 }}
                onPress={() => console.log("cancel!")}
            />
            <View >
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>cancel</Text>
            </View>
            <Avatar
                size='large'
                activeOpacity={0.2}
                rounded
                source={require('../assets/up.png')} style={{ height: 80, width: 80 }}
                onPress={() => console.log("Works!")}
            />
            <View>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>ok</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is wrapping the avatar and the text by TouchableOpacity.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("cancel!")}>
        <Avatar
            size='large'
            containerStyle={{ marginTop: 30 }}
            activeOpacity={0.2}
            rounded
            source={require('../assets/down.png')} style={{ height: 80, width: 80 }}
        />
        <View >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>cancel</Text>
        </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**I recommend to write your own styles by using basic react native elements. Try to use least number of 3rd party plugins. Good luck.**

Answer (score 0):

The best option is Wrapping the avatar and text with TouchableOpacity. and Add some more Styles like below

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{
                backgroundColor: '#00BFFF',
                display : "flex",
                alignItems: 'flex-start',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                marginTop: 30,
                borderBottomWidth: 2,
                borderColor: 'blue',

            }} onPress={() => {}>
        <Avatar
            size='large'
            containerStyle={{ marginTop: 30 }}
            activeOpacity={0.2}
            rounded
            source={require('../assets/down.png')} style={{ height: 80, width: 80 }}
        />
        <View >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>cancel || ok</Text>
        </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is like that because of the styles you have given to view. You have given a flex direction row which will place all your elements in a row. You have given four elements in your root view which has style flex-direction row so all four elements in that view (2 Avatar component and 2 text) will be placed side by side in a row.
if you want text below image i thin you should put avatar and text box in a view and give that a view a flex-direction column like:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("cancel!")>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>
            <Avatar>
            <View>
                <Text />
            </View>
        <View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("works!")>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>
            <Avatar>
            <View>
                <Text />
            </View>
        <View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
<View>
```

hope this helps in someway :)